# Not able to login to a newly created user using ssh keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I recently created a new server from backup server in azure. In that server, I'm trying to create a user but user is not being created.

I'm able to see the user in the list of users but I'm unable to ssh the user, I'm getting public key denied. I checked and for that particular user, home directory is not created and hence ssh details are not stored for him to connect.

I tried creating a password based user. Same as before, home directory was not created.

How to resolve this issue?

EDIT 1: mrc02_kr

```
root@server:/home/sid# adduser user1
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Adding user `user1' ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Adding new group `user1' (1005) ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Adding new user `user1' (1005) with group `user1' ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Creating home directory `/home/user1' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for user1
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

Edit 2: I found this when I ran **getent passwd**

```
user1:x:1008:1008::/home/user1:
user2:x:1007:1007:,,,:/home/user2:/bin/bash
```

I'm able to login to user1 but not user2

Comment: Any error messages when trying to create the user? Log file entries?

Comment: Could you show the command you are using to create and file `/etc/defaults/useradd` ?

Comment: @RudiC : root@server:/home/sid# adduser user1
Adding user `user1' ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Adding new group `user1' (1005) ...
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
Creating home directory `/home/user1' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y

Comment: @RudiC I'm unable to add entire result as comment has character limit but I'm able to create the user by adding ssh key or password based but when I try to ssh him, I'll always get public key denied error

Comment: @mrc02_kr : how to access /etc/defaults/useradd?

Comment: But if I use the same key in any other servers, user is able to login

Comment: @SidtheGooner Please edit your original post and paste thehe output of useradd command.